# CubeMap in OpenGL doesn't show at all

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm trying to simply load 6 pictures as texture of cube in OpenGL. Blow is the loading code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

for (int i = 0;i < 6;++i)
{
    int width, height, channel;
    unsigned char* img = SOIL_load_image(skybox[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &channel, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO);
    glTexImage2D(cubeTarget[i], 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    delete img;
}

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARB);
```

The rendering code is passed. The weird thing is that the cube rendered is white. It seems that the texture isn't loaded at all. I change the loading code to see whether a 2D texture will work:

```
glGenTextures(1, texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
int width, height, channel;
unsigned char* img = SOIL_load_image(skybox[0].c_str(), &width, &height, &channel, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
delete img;

if(texture[0] == 0) return false;

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The result is I can see the texture after all, no matter how strange the distribution caused by the texture coordinates. I gathered the following information:

1. The lib I use for loading image works well;
2. The setting of the cubemap is from the SuperBibble chapter 9. Almost the same code will work well when I compiling the code of the book.

BTW, does anyone have some suggestion about loading image library? The one I use seems to stop updating for a really long time...

*Appending: What I find out now is that if I try to only load one img as all the skybox faces' texture, it will be shown. As long as use a variable to replace a specific value, nothing won't be displayed.*

Comment: How/where do you set up the mipmaps? (and if you don't, why have you enabled them?)

Comment: @JasonD You mean the minification filter? I actually didn't build up mipmap. It still won't work when I change it to GL_LINEAR. So I guess that's not the problem.

Comment: "*The one I use seems to stop updating for a really long time...*" SOIL? SOIL is *complete*; it has all the features the owner wants to give it. At which point, there's no need to update it.

Comment: As to your question, you don't explain how you're actually trying to *render* using this cubemap.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, then thx :) But I'm still eager to know which point is wrong in my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out. It's because the **resolution** of the last picture is different from the others.

Realy kind of wasting a lot of time.